# What must an external JavaScript file look like to avoid global variables and methods?

Tags: javascript, yui, global-variables

I have the following piece of code on my page:

```
<script src="/Assets/JavaScripts/myJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     testAlert();

</script>
```

And in myJavaScript.js I have the following:

```
(function () {
     function testAlert() {
          alert('test alert');
     }
})();
```

It's not calling `testAlert`.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here?  I'm trying to avoid global variables and methods.  I did something similiar in jQuery and it worked, it just required a $ at the start of the external file.  Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong here and how to make sure I follow best practices?

Answer (score 2):

I put your code in my environment and checked, I got error in mozila error console.
So, Please check it there.
you should put only below javascript function in myjavascript.js file.

```
function testAlert() {
    alert('test alert');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the (function () {})(); part?

Comment: @Brendan:  Basically, it creates a function and runs it immediately.  In your case, and in the case of jQuery plugins (which are usually written like `(function($) { ...... })(jQuery);`, it (1) makes pretty sure that jQuery is available as `$` (even if it's in no-conflict mode, which makes `$` not mean `jQuery` anymore), and (2) creates a space where you can stick private global stuff, thanks to the spiff of closures.

Answer (score 1):

Your function in the js-file isn't returning anything. To avoid global variables you could create one global namespace (-like) variable:

```
var myNS = (function () {
     function testAlert() {
          alert('test alert');
     }
     return {testAlert:testAlert};
}());
```

Now you can use `myNS.testalert()` in your inline javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JS is made in such a way that you really *can't* totally avoid globals.  (Well, you can, sort of.  If you never give anything a name.  But that tends to cause more problems than it solves.)  When you call `testAlert` from some other script, you're operating under the assumption that `testAlert` is global.  If it weren't, you couldn't just call it from anywhere like that.

You can minimize the chance of collision, though, by adding your stuff to an object that serves as a namespace, like so:

```
// don't clear it out if it already exists.
// that way all of your scripts can use your namespace, if you want.
// what you're really trying to protect against, are strangers picking names
// like yours. 
if (!window.myNamespace) myNamespace = {};

// example function
myNamespace.testAlert = function() { alert("test alert"); };


myNamespace.testAlert();
```

This way, the only name that has a good chance of conflicting is `myNamespace`.

I was going to show an example of a namespaced global...but ya know what?  A namespaced global is *still a global*.  Global variables are something you want to try and get rid of in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need *some* sort of global variable so that you can access the method you're looking for. The fact that you have `<script>testAlert()</script>` means you expect `testAlert()` to be defined in the global namespace.

What I like to do (especially when using YUI, which you have tagged this question with), is to create a global object that acts as a utility class.

```
var page = {
    init: function() {
        // Do some initialization...
    },
    testAlert: function() {
        alert("Test Alert");
    }
};
```

After you do that, you can use the single global "page" variable to access everything you need.

```
// e.g.
page.testAlert();

// or...
Y.on("domready", page.init, page);
```

Again, for the second example I'm assuming you're using YUI, since you tagged this question with it.